# Usb Speaker with External Power supply? S ll

Tags: usb, external-sd, charging, hardware, speaker

I'm using a 2x3W yenkee usb speaker with my phone through an usb otg cable and it's working fine, but when I turn the volume up the speaker turns off.I assume it's because of the high power consumption, because if I plug it into my pc it works even when i turn it all the way up. I was wondering whether an external charger would solve the problem, that way I could plug the usb into the charger and the jack into my phone.I'm not sure though if it works. Do you think it's a viable solution?

Comment: Does the speaker have it's own battery?

Comment: Yes, please try to charge the speaker while you turn the volume up and see if it still plays music. Then it means the speakers require more power which the mobile couldn't provide. And this may affect your battery in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I tried to power it with pluging it into a common charger and I'm happy to say it worked and didn't cut out .Considering the external charger use the same method to give power it really should work. Although I haven't had the chance to try it yet but I'll definitely grab one so i could max out my speakers volume anywhere I am.

Adam